# Polygon with dash-dot-dash border style

Tags: symbology, arcgis-api-wpf

I'm developing a WPF application. One of my requirements is to have polygon borders drawn with a dash-dot-dash style. Is there a way to accomplish that in the client side?

So far I've tried:

```
var graphic = new Graphic();
graphic.Symbol = new SimpleFillSymbol
{
    BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 255)),
    BorderThickness = 5
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define a [CartographicLineSymbol](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/wpf/apiref/ESRI.ArcGIS.Client~ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Symbols.CartographicLineSymbol_members.html) with a custom [DashArray](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/wpf/apiref/ESRI.ArcGIS.Client~ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Symbols.CartographicLineSymbol~DashArray.html). If you have adjacent polygons, I recommend you to first convert your polygons to lines because two adjacent polygons each have a borders and the patterns could overlap in a wrong way. Display those lines on top of polygons without outlines and the rendering will be as you want. Below is an illustration on the use of dashArray to create dash-dot-dash lines.

[image]

the "grammar" for this line would be 5,2,1,2 (stroke of 5 (=dash), gap of 2, stroke of 1 (=dot), gap of 2 )